# Convertir cvs a un formato especifico con pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo csv a un formato especifico guardado es una variable usando pandas.

He intentado convertir a Json

```
datosEntrada = pd.read_csv("prueba1.csv").to_json('prueba1')
```

El formato csv tiene las siguientes columnas

```
edad,genero,raza,ejercicio,fuma,cronica,sobrepeso,alcohol,antecedentes,presionArterial
```

Con los siguientes datos

```
Mas,Masculino,Afrodescendiente,NoEjercicio,Fuma,Cronica,Sobrepeso,Alcohol,Antecedentes,Mayor
```

El formato esperado debe ser de la siguiente manera. ¿Como puedo construir el csv a este formato especifico?

```
{ 'edad':'Mas','genero':'Femenino','raza':'Afrodescendiente','ejercicio':'NoEjercicio','fuma':'Fuma','cronica':'Cronica','sobrepeso':'Sobrepeso','alcohol':'Alcohol','antecedentes':'Antecedentes','presionArterial':'Mayor'}
```

Comment: Hola alec_, deberías agregar un ejemplo de archivo csv de partida y su salida esperada.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, ya he editado la pregunta con la estructura del csv y el formato de salida esperado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de exportar los datos como los necesitas, es por un lado especificar que columnas quieres exportar y en que orden quieres tomar los datos, y por otro, indicar que no quieres el indice. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd

datos_csv = pd.read_csv("prueba1.csv")
# Esto solo en caso de que vengan mas columnas que no quieras exportar, fijate es tu caso: 
datos_para_exportar = datos_csv[['edad','genero','raza','ejercicio','fuma','cronica','sobrepeso','alcohol','antecedentes','presionArterial']]
# Esta linea te dará el formato que necesitas sobre los datos a exportar:
datos_para_exportar.to_json("prueba.json",orient='records')
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
[{"edad":"Mas","genero":"Femenino","raza":"Afrodescendiente","ejercicio":"NoEjercicio","fuma":"Fuma","cronica":"Cronica","sobrepeso":"Sobrepeso","alcohol":"Alcohol","antecedentes":"Antecedentes","presionArterial":"Mayor"}]
```

---

**Para exportar sólo un registro como objeto json**:

Si lo que deseas es exportar solamente un registro específico con el formato que lo solicitas, es decir, sin corchetes, el código que debes usar es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

datos_csv = pd.read_csv("prueba1.csv")
# Esto solo en caso de que vengan mas columnas que no quieras exportar, fijate es tu caso: 
datos_para_exportar = datos_csv[['edad','genero','raza','ejercicio','fuma','cronica','sobrepeso','alcohol','antecedentes','presionArterial']]
# Aqui determinas el registro que quieres exportar (en este caso es el primero, de indice 0), como objeto json:
datos_para_exportar.loc[0].to_json("prueba.json")
```

El resultado será:

```
{ "edad": "Mas", "genero": "Femenino", "raza": "Afrodescendiente", "ejercicio": "NoEjercicio", "fuma": "Fuma", "cronica": "Cronica", "sobrepeso": "Sobrepeso", "alcohol": "Alcohol", "antecedentes": "Antecedentes", "presionArterial": "Mayor" }
```

Si demás quieres que las comillas dobles sean reemplazadas por simples, el código sería este:

```
import pandas as pd

datos_csv = pd.read_csv("prueba1.csv")
# Esto solo en caso de que vengan mas columnas que no quieras exportar, fijate es tu caso: 
datos_para_exportar = datos_csv[['edad','genero','raza','ejercicio','fuma','cronica','sobrepeso','alcohol','antecedentes','presionArterial']]
# Aqui determinas el registro que quieres exportar (en este caso es el primero, de indice 0), como objeto json
# y reemplazamos las comillas dobles por simples:
output_json = datos_para_exportar.loc[0].to_json().replace('"',"'")
# Guardamos la cadena generadad con el formato indicado:
with open("prueba.json", 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(output_json)
```

El resultado será:

```
{'edad':'Mas','genero':'Femenino','raza':'Afrodescendiente','ejercicio':'NoEjercicio','fuma':'Fuma','cronica':'Cronica','sobrepeso':'Sobrepeso','alcohol':'Alcohol','antecedentes':'Antecedentes','presionArterial':'Mayor'}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Leonardo, gracias por tu respuesta, tengo una pregunta. ¿Es posible obtener los datos sin los corchetes cuadrados y con comillas sencillas?

Comment: Bien, si es solo un registro, ahora agrego la respuesta para contemplarlo.

Comment: Funciona excelente, muchas gracias Leonardo. Saludos